# When do rescue missions have an agent as the hostage?

Tags: invisible-inc

When I've done rescue missions, I've always had less than 4 agents, so the prisoner always seemed to end up being an agent that I could add to my team.

Once I've reached the max of 4 agents, is it possible to add more agents as "reserve" agents by doing more rescue missions, or do the rescue missions only have sellable hostages at that point?

If I end up having to leave my 4th agent behind on a mission, does the next rescue mission have that agent being held prisoner, or is it a new random agent, or is it a sellable hostage?

Answer (score 6):

> Once I've reached the max of 4 agents, is it possible to add more agents as "reserve" agents by doing more rescue missions, or do the rescue missions only have sellable hostages at that point?

The game actually does a neat trick (at least from what I've could read in five minutes). Per default, the mission will contain only a prisoner. Only when you open the actual room, the game will randomly decide whether the prisoner is an agent or a regular hostage.

The associated file contains the following lines in the swapping function (mission_detention_centre.lua):

```
local unit = mission_util.findUnitByTag( sim, "prisoner" )
if unit == nil then
    return -- No prisoner to swap?!
end

if #sim:getPC():getAgents() >= simdefs.AGENT_LIMIT then
    return -- Maxxed out agents
end
```

whereas `AGENT_LIMIT` is set to `4` in simdefs.lua. So if you have four agents then a rescue missions will always contain a sellable hostage.

Comment: Good answer, though I wouldn't have thought to say "The game actually does a neat trick" - I'd've said something like "The game (predictably/uninterestingly) always does what you suspected. Despite the description of uncertainty, there's always an agent if you have less than 4, and never one if you have 4."

Comment: I think the "neat trick" part is from the idea that the prisoner/agent logic is decided when you open the room or maybe the fact that a prisoner might be swapped with an agent.

Comment: `mission_detention_centre.lua` has a `getLostAgent()` method commented with "-- Get the earliest captured agent from the list." So it does seem you can get MIA agents back. Two other variables make me think you might randomly _not_ get an agent, even if you have less than 4: `simdefs.NORMAL_DIFFICULTY` and `CHANCE_OF_AGENT_IN_DETENTION`, which is set to 50%. Someone more familiar with .lua files and the game variables can check in the `checkPrisonerAgentSwap()` method that @Zeta mentions.

Comment: You can get an agent back, and they still have all the augmentations and equipment they had when you lost them.